# Why I have issue using arduino portable version with esp32 boards only?

Tags: compilation, arduino-esp32, xtensa

I am trying portable arduino ide, following this tutorial :
https://docs.arduino.cc/software/ide-v1/tutorials/PortableIDE

if I compile empty sketch for arduino AVR boards, it works, but if I do that for esp32 boards, I have this issue :
c:\users\pasca\downloads\arduino-1.8.19-windows\arduino-1.8.19\portable\packages\esp32\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc\gcc8_4_0-esp-2021r2-patch3\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0\cstdlib:41:10: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory

I specify that I had add esp32 boards from :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/gh-pages/package_esp32_index.json

I tried with arduino sam board and it is ok.

The empty sketch is :

```
void setup() {
```

// put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

[arduino uno compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sikFU.png)

[esp32 compile with portable version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TQEn.png)

[esp32 compile with "normal" version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv4mY.png)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

try to run Arduino IDE AS administration
and in the border choice ==> ESP32 DEV MODE

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.
I tried but it don't work.

I will end up giving up... sniff...